# Date fields in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql, date, phpmyadmin

I am using `Mysql` database to store the data.

I am facing some issues regarding `date` fields. Date is stored in `YYYY-MM-DD` format in database. when i am retrieving date from database I am using the following code.

```
echo(date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row_getsavedetails['Purchase_WarrantyStartDate'])));
```

this is working fine if a date is present in the database.

If there is no date in the database '01/01/1970' is getting displayed in the front end.

I am not able to understand, how this date is coming up.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Firoz, phpMyAdmin is not a database. It is just an interface for mySQL.

Comment: You just want to know why you get 1970? Or you want to know how to avoid it?

Answer (score 5):

[UNIX timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) are expressed as seconds relative to Jan. 1st 1970 UTC. `strtotime` turns a date written in human readable format into UNIX timestamps. If there is no valid date, it returns `false`. `date` interprets its second parameter as integer, as UNIX timestamp. Therefore it casts `false` to `0`. `0` is zero seconds from Jan. 1st 1970. Hence, you get 01.01.1970.

Answer (score 1):

Why not check before `echoing?`

```
if(!empty($row_getsavedetails['Purchase_WarrantyStartDate']))
{
 echo(date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row_getsavedetails['Purchase_WarrantyStartDate'])));
}
else { echo "Date is not available"; }
```

The fact you get `01/01/1970` , See `deceze's` [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22092360/1003917)

Comment: This is fine Shankar. But I am facing other problem. I am having a form where user can enter data along with save option.In that form I have date fields which are not mandatory and when ever user clicks on save by default this date '01/01/1970' is getting saved in the database. I am not getting why this is happening.

Comment: i will show along with the field. Then suggest me the best solution.

Comment: <input name="txtmoni" id="txtmoni" value="<?php echo empty($row_getsavedetails['Purchase_WarrantyStartDate']) ?: date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row_getsavedetails['Purchase_WarrantyStartDate'])); ?>"   type="text"/>   I tried what you have told me but it is not working.

Comment: Use this `<?php echo !empty($row_getsavedetails['Purchase_WarrantyStartDate']) ? date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row_getsavedetails['Purchase_WarrantyStartDate'])) : 'Date N/A'; ?>`

Comment: i tried this it is not working shankar. Still 01-01-1970 is coming up

Answer (score 0):

01/01/1970 is the default unix timestamp if left NULL. Best to add a check to handle NULL values in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the Default date returned if the value you try and convert is null.
You will have to check if the date is empty first.

```
echo empty($row_getsavedetails['Purchase_WarrantyStartDate']) ? "Date is null" : date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row_getsavedetails['Purchase_WarrantyStartDate']));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to know that dates are represented (almost anywhere in a computer) like the number of miliseconds from 1/1/1970. 
So if you are getting that date it means that the value you inserted in the database (by default) when creating the date was 0.